# Why are images in my private album visible without a password?

Tags: privacy, photobucket

I am having a hard time understanding how the **Private** albums feature of Photobucket works.

This what I've done so far:

1. Created an album called "private".
2. Set a **guest password** for the album.
3. Uploaded a single test image to this album.

Now, when I share the album's URL with someone, they must enter the guest password to view the test image.

> Album URL: http://s1336.photobucket.com/user/iglvzx/library/private
> Password: `abcd1234`

But when I share the image's URL, no password is required!

> http://s1336.photobucket.com/user/iglvzx/media/private/secret_zpsb9924305.png.html

It is worth noting, that when viewing the image through this URL, clicking the "private" album name at the top of the page prompts you for the guest password.

Am I missing something? Or is this by design?

---

**Edit:** I tried disabling the "Allow others to copy my photos & videos" setting under `Privacy > Content Privacy`, but that does not change the ability to get or visit the image URL without a password.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. In the [Album Privacy Settings Explained](http://support.photobucket.com/entries/21124003-Album-Privacy-Settings-Explained) support article, Photobucket writes:

> **Password Protected Albums**
>
> When an album is password protected:
>
> - Users enter the password in order to view the album.
> - If someone searches for your username, they cannot access your password protected albums unless they have a guest password.
> - Content will not display in search results.
> - ***Guests to your album can copy and share photos in the album*** - this cannot be disabled, so only share with people you trust!

Unfortunately, you can only password protect access to the album and its "directory listing", but not the individual image wrapper pages themselves.